# Drupal 7, if contextual filter 'default value' not there, ignore it

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-contextual-filters

The answer might be very simple but I can not find any solution to it.

I have a view with contextual filter for Nid with default value set to 'current node ID'. The block yields correct results when were are on /node/5 which has results. However, I want the block shows ALL results (remove the filter?!) when the block is placed on the  or somewhere where 'node ID' is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option of validations when the filter value is not available. You can choose the first option of  Display all results for the specified field.

[image]

Comment: Then it will return ALL results even when in /node/5 . It will not filter based on the NID!?

Comment: This will return all results if there is no filter, otherwise displays matched results based on the filter values.